# Как отправить сообщение определенному клиенту express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, websocket, express

Делаю виджет чата с менеджером используя JS, firebase.db и сервак на express.js. Отправляю сообщения с помощью Websocket на сервак данные от пользователя и не могу понять как отправить эти данные именно менеджеру. То есть отправить всем пользователям, которые подключены к серваку понятно, а как выделить определенное соединение не понятно.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stackoverflow. а нужно через чистый `websocket` или можно и через `socket.io`?

Comment: Я использовал чистый Websocket. Но в принципе если есть пример через socket.io то и в нем я разберусь думаю

Answer (score 0):

Значит, первое: это [пример](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) чата для присоеденения `socket.io` к експресс

Далее, можно придумать что-то похожого до перехватчика

```js
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
...
let prime_user = undefined;
io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
   const session_id = socket.id;
   socket.on('msg',(msg)=>{
      if(msg==='prime_user'){
         prime_user = session_id;
      }
   });
});
```

а дальше кидаем `emit` на нашего менеджера:

```js
io.to(prime_user).emit('newMessage','someStringData');
```

дополнительно для обучения `emit` пригодится ещё вот [это](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/)